# How can I have an entire folder be an embedded resource in a Visual Studio project?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm working on a project which we'll call Container.  Container has a bunch of EmbeddedResources.  The original files for these EmbeddedResources are another project which we'll call FileProject.

FileProject is a project that is currently being worked on by a group of different developers and is always changing, so I have my EmbeddedResource files linked - so that whenever the original project changes and I do a rebuild of my project, it picks up the changes.

This setup catches whenever a file changes, but it doesn't catch whenever a new file is added or removed from the project.  Is there a way to make EmbeddedResources out of an entire folder structure in Visual Studio to catch file removal and additions?

Comment: Are you guys using SVN inside of VS? e.g. http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/ Seems like this would be a great start for multiple engineers working on a shared project.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question though.

Comment: Massive amounts of embedded resources are a really poor substitute for a setup.exe file.  Have you ever run SysInternals' VMMap on your process?  A .zip file would be a simple approach to solve this particular problem.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Edit the project file for Container in a text editor and find the `<EmbeddedResource>` elements that link to the files in FileProject:

```xml
<EmbeddedResource Include="..\FileProject\Copy.bmp">
  <Link>Copy.bmp</Link>
</EmbeddedResource>
<EmbeddedResource Include="..\FileProject\Paste.bmp">
  <Link>Paste.bmp</Link>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

Delete all of these elements and replace them with a single `<EmbeddedResource>` element that has a suitable wildcard:

```xml
<EmbeddedResource Include="..\FileProject\*.bmp" />
```

Now if you add Cut.bmp to FileProject, it will also show up in Container.

Comment: This approach works although the newly added files show up in .csproj file with Build action Content but they also act as EmbeddedResource in practice.