# Add all files in folder (including sub dir) as embedded resource?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have a database project, and I am embedding all files within a certain folder structure.  The problem is that I also will be creating additional folders within that structure.

I can specify a specific folder to include all *.sql files and that works perfectly. However, in this instance I won't know what future folders there are.  Is there any way to do a --recurse?

I was using this as a reference:
[How can I have an entire folder be an embedded resource in a Visual Studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994258/how-can-i-have-an-entire-folder-be-an-embedded-resource-in-a-visual-studio-proje)

Answer (score 6):

This should include all `*.sql` files recursively:

```xml
<EmbeddedResource Include="SqlFiles\**\*.sql" />
```

Note the `**` to indicate recursion.